# ValueError: could not convert string to float: :'30/01/20'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gaussian

i keep getting this error any appreciated

i been trying this but value error shows up https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jEmsG9WWRpUmuU92URD0PxtzWkpETlY3?usp=sharing

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

import datetime 




df = pd.read_csv('/content/covid_19_india.csv')
df['split'] = np.random.randn(df.shape[0], 1)

msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) <= 0.7

training = df[msk]
test = df[~msk]


xtrain = training.drop('Sno', axis=1)
ytrain = training.loc[:, 'Sno']
xtest = test.drop('Sno', axis=1)
ytest = test.loc[:, 'Sno']



model = GaussianNB()


model.fit(xtrain, ytrain)


pred = model.predict(xtest)


mat = confusion_matrix(pred, ytest)
names = np.unique(pred)
sns.heatmap(mat, square=True, annot=True, fmt='d', cbar=False,
            xticklabels=names, yticklabels=names)
plt.xlabel('Truth')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
```

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
31
32 # Train the model
---> 33 model.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
34
35 # Predict Output

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
83
84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
86
87

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '30/01/20'

any help

Comment: What were you expecting? this is not a floating number: `'30/01/20'`, it's a date! You're probably reading the wrong column from the input file.

Comment: hello there thanks for replying  i am  student this is for project .  prediction is the goal . can you  help me with confusion_matrix using GaussianNB()

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that "30/01/20" string could not be
converted to *float*.

So it seems that your DataFrame contains a column with dates.

Note that when *read_csv* reads source data, it attempts to convert
numeric columns to either *int* or *float*, but other columns
(which can not be converted this way) are left as strings and
these columns have *object* data type.

Start from identification which column contains dates.
Then, to convert this column to *datetime*, as early as at
the reading phase, pass *parse_dates* parameter to *read_csv*,
with a list of column names to be converted.

Then at least there should be no problem with conversion to *float*.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in both the comments and the other answer to this question, you have a column of dates formatted as strings in your dataset. You have a couple options here.

#### Don't use the date column

For the sake of argument, let's say your dates are in a column named `df['dates']`. You can simply drop the date column if you do not want to use it.

```py
df.drop('date', axis=1)
```

#### Convert dates to datetime format

Another option is to convert this column to datetime format. This can be done using `apply()` and `datetime.datetime.strptime`. If you're an aspiring data scientist you should read and then bookmark https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior. It's pretty handy, I promise.

```py
from datetime import datetime
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda d:datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%y')
```